# Why is jQuery fadeIn effect not working when I reverse the order?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement fadein effect for the picture, where there's picture 1, 2 and 3. When I fadeIn picture following sequence, the fadeIn effect works. However, if I click the picture link in backward, example picture 3 then picture 2, you won't see the fadeIn effect. Not sure what mistake I did here.

Here's the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            #wrapper{
                width:400px;
                height:300px;
            }
        
            .picture{
                width:400px;
                height:300px;
                position:absolute;
            }
        
            .button{
                background-color:red;
                width:300px;
                height:200px;
            }
        
        
        </style>    
        <script type="text/javascript">         
            function switchPicture(id){
                visible_image_id = jQuery("img:visible").attr("id");
            
                jQuery("#image_"+id).fadeIn(500,function(){
                    console.log("visible -" + visible_image_id);
                    jQuery("#"+visible_image_id).hide();
                });             
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='wrapper'>
            <img id='image_1' class='picture' style="display:block;" src="http://media.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/uploader/images/wallpaper-calendar-august-11/lion__11.jpg">
            <img id='image_2' class='picture' style="display:block;" src="http://media.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/uploader/images/wallpaper-calendar-august-11/before_the_fall__39.jpg">                                   
            <img id='image_3' class='picture' style="display:block;" src="http://media.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/uploader/images/wallpaper-calendar-august-11/hot_august__97.jpg">                                                
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="javascript:switchPicture(1);">Picture 1</a>
            <a href="javascript:switchPicture(2);">Picture 2</a>            
            <a href="javascript:switchPicture(3);">Picture 3</a>                        
        </div>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using one of the bajillion jQuery plugins that's already out there?

Comment: I build this for custom purpose, found it faster to build from scratch, but stuck in this problem.

Comment: I guess it's not so fast when you have to stop and troubleshoot.

Comment: Yea, you are right. But, there's tons of plugins to choose from and I have to customize it in later stage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a z-index issue.  The problem is that if you are say, showing image 2 with image 3 already shown.  Image 3 is in front of image 2, so you will not see image 2 until 3 is hidden.  3 isn't hidden until after the fade completes.  You can fix this by setting the z-index of the images.

```
function switchPicture(id) {
    visible_image_id = jQuery("img:visible").css("zIndex", 0).attr("id");

    jQuery("#image_" + id).fadeIn(500, function() {
        console.log("visible -" + visible_image_id);
        jQuery("#" + visible_image_id).hide();
    }).css("zIndex", 1);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7kQWG/

EDIT: Some additional improvements.  You should ideally get rid of the inline javascript in the href and replace it with a click handler.  Something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("a").click(function() {
        var visible_image_id = jQuery("img:visible").css("zIndex", 0).attr("id");
        var new_image_id = "image_" + ($(this).index() + 1);

        if(visible_image_id == new_image_id) return false;

        jQuery("#" + new_image_id).fadeIn(500, function() {
            console.log("visible -" + visible_image_id);
            jQuery("#" + visible_image_id).hide();
        }).css("zIndex", 1);

        return false;
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7kQWG/1

Also note, I added `if(visible_image_id == new_image_id) return false;`.  This will fix the bug where it was hiding the image entirely if you clicked on the link of the visible image.

For extra bonus points, you can replace the href with a URL to a no-javascript page.  That way if the user doesn't have javascript enabled, they will be taken to that page but if javascript is on the intended behavior will occur.

Comment: Voted up, deleted my answer, but would be really sweet if you could turn that into a click handler and get rid of the inline function invocations.

Comment: @kingjiv, This is life savior! I figured it out late that it might be ordering issue, but you shown it so precisely. Thank you so much!

Comment: @karim79 well alright, just for you!  http://jsfiddle.net/7kQWG/1/  I also fixed the problem with clicking on the same link twice in a row.

Comment: @kingjiv - Nice! You totally added value to the thread. You should add that to your answer to turn it into a "rep farming robot" :D

Comment: @karim79 Hah, I'll go ahead and add it I guess.